# JUnit test on getter method not working

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am working on a Java exercise in Eclipse to add JUnit tests to a existing project. This isn't for an assignment or anything, just a way to get used to Eclipse (I had been using BlueJ previously). 
However, the two test methods I have written don't seem to be working. For some reasons, the Circle objects I have created (which have a radius field, which I have set as 6, 8 and 2 to three different circles) keep defaulting to a radius of 0, so both of my test methods (one does actually report to work, but this is because it is checking the circumference is >= 0) fail. What have I done wrong? I am not an experienced programmer so the mistake may be obvious to most of you.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class CircleTest {
    Circle circle1;
    Circle circle2;
    Circle circle3;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    circle1 = new Circle(6.00);
    circle2 = new Circle(8.00);
    circle3 = new Circle(2.00);
}




@Test
public void testCircumference() {
    assertTrue(circle1.circumference() >= 0);
    assertTrue(circle2.circumference() >= 0);
    assertTrue(circle3.circumference() >= 0);

}

@Test
public void testGetter() {
    assertEquals(6, circle1.getRadius(), 1e-15);
    assertEquals(8, circle2.getRadius(), 1e-15);
    assertEquals(2, circle3.getRadius(), 1e-15);

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

}
```

Comment: Looks fine. I suspect your `Circle` class. Can you post that too?

Comment: It would help if you could post the source code of the Circle class too.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the value returned by `getRadius` is the default value of `0.0` for `double` primitive types

Ensure the radius is assigned in the constructor of `Circle`

```
public Circle(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

so that the value can be returned by `getRadius`

```
public double getRadius() {
   return radius;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html 
In 2  words: floating points should not be compared by equals - you should compare them by their absolute difference: a - b < 0.00001, for example.
I think, it is a root of a problem here.

Comment: assertEquals() for floating types takes a tolerance, in effect doing exactly what you are suggesting. The OP's use of assertEquals() is correct.

Comment: Wow, did not know that. Very interesting. Usually, I delete my wrong answers, but this I'll leave because of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use dobules or floats for the radius. Working with these types can be tricky, since they are not precise.
Unit test frameworks provide special comparison methods for this case:

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double,%20double%29

So you would use for example

```
 assertEquals(6, circle1.getRadius(), 0.0001);
```

Comment: That `1e-15` in the OP’s example is the same thing (so-called “delta”) as `0.0001` in yours, except much smaller number for more precise comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The error must be in the `Circle` class. Your tests, though they have some minor flaws, seem okay.

1. Since you are using JUnit 4 annotations, you need not name your `@Before` method `setUp`.
2. You down't need a `tearDown` method, since it is empty.  You also don't need to name it `tearDown`.
3. These classes should have but one `assert`, Were something wrong with `circle1`, you'll never test `circle2` and `circle3`. In fact, you should look up *parameterized JUnit tests*.

So, what should your `Circle` class look like?  Here's an idea, and some hooks for test writing.

```
public class Circle implements Serializable {
    private static long serialVersionUid = ...;

    private final double radius;

    public Circle(final double radius) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (radius <= 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attempt to create a circle with nonpositive radius" + radius);
        }
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public double getRadius() {...}
    public double getCircumference{...}
}
```

Now, test that:

1. `new Circle(-10.0)` throws.
2. `new Circle(Double.NaN)` throws,
3. `new Circle(10.0)` succeeds.
4. `(new Circle(10.0)).getRadius()` returns `10`.
5. `(new Circle(10.0)).getCircumference()` returns approximately `31.4159`.
6. `Circle` implements `Serializable`.